# What does $Q_v$ mean in mathematics?

Tags: integration, notation, bessel-functions

I am reading an equation required to solve a particular integral involving Bessel function it says:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-at}J_v(bt)J_v(ct)\text{d}t=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{bc}}Q_{v-\frac{1}{2}}\left (\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2bc}\right )$$
where $J$ are the Bessel function of first kind. However, the text does not mention what is $Q_{v-\frac{1}{2}}$ is this also a bessel function. It doesn't look like to be the error function the only function that I am familiar with to have $Q$.

**The book where the equation is given is: A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions by G. N. Watson, pp. 389.**

Comment: You should always give a full text/internet (or other) reference for a question such as this. Notation varies quite a bit in mathematical literature. Although there are many standard notations that most everyone consistently uses, it's likely that if YOU don't know the notation for something, then it's one of those things that will vary in the literature, hence you need to give a reasonably complete citation (e.g. if the book has more than one edition, then the edition should be given, since notation is sometimes changed when editions are changed).

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro Done.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that page 389 suddenly uses new notation in the middle of an equation that was not defined anywhere in the vicinity of this equation nor anywhere on the previous 388 pages, nor is something standard. Most likely you just have to search for it more carefully.

Comment: This turns out to be Legendre function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Q_\nu$ is a type of Legendre function. If we define first **the** Legendre function (or "Ferrer's function of the first kind)

$$P^\mu_{\nu}(x)=\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{\mu/2}~{}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}1+\nu ,-\nu \\ 1-\mu\end{matrix}~\bigg| ~ \frac{1-x}{2}\right)$$

Where
$${}_p F_q\left(\begin{matrix}a_1,\dots,a_p \\ b_1,\dots ,b_q\end{matrix}~\bigg|~z\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \prod_{i=1}^p\frac{\Gamma(a_i+k)}{\Gamma(a_i)}\cdot \prod_{j=1}^q\frac{\Gamma(b_j)}{\Gamma(b_j+k)}\cdot \frac{z^k}{k!}$$
Is a generalized hypergeometric function, then we can define the complementary Legendre function (or "Ferrer's function of the second kind")
$$Q^\mu_\nu(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}\cot(\mu\pi) P^\mu_\nu(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{csc}(\mu\pi)\frac{\Gamma(1+\nu+\mu)}{\Gamma(1+\nu-\mu)}\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{\mu}P^{-\mu}_{\nu}(x)$$

We then define
$$Q_{\nu}(x):=Q^0_{\nu}(x)$$
Unfortunately the above definition for $Q^\mu_{\nu}$ breaks down when $\mu=0$ (because $\cot(0)$ is undefined) but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_function#Solutions_of_the_differential_equation) offers another definition

$$Q^\mu_{\nu}(z)=\frac{\sqrt \pi~\Gamma(\nu+\mu+1)}{2^{\nu+1}\Gamma(\nu+3/2)}\frac{\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\mu\pi}(z^2-1)^{\mu/2}}{z^{\nu+\mu+1}}~{}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{\nu+\mu+1}{2},\frac{\nu+\mu+2}{2} \\ \nu+\frac{3}{2}\end{matrix}~\bigg|~\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$$

Though keep in mind that conventions differ across sources, i.e, Wiki's definition for $P^\mu_\nu$ includes a prefactor of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\mu)}$. With this in mind it appears that
$$Q_\nu(z):=Q^0_\nu(z)=\frac{\sqrt \pi~\Gamma(\nu+1)}{2^{\nu+1}\Gamma(\nu+3/2)}\frac{1}{z^{\nu+1}}~{}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{\nu+1}{2},\frac{\nu+2}{2} \\ \nu+\frac{3}{2}\end{matrix}~\bigg|~\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$$

In the case that $\nu=m$ is an integer Wiki provides the direct formula

$$Q_n(x)=\frac{n!}{1\cdot 3\cdots (2n+1)}\left(x^{-n-1}+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2(2n+3)}x^{-n-3}+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}{2\cdot 4\cdot (2n+3)(2n+5)}x^{-n-5}+\cdots\right)$$

Or [Bonnet's recursion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Definition_via_generating_function)

$$Q_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) & n=0 \\ P_1(x)Q_0(x)-1 & n=1 \\ \frac{2n-1}{n}x~Q_{n-1}(x)-\frac{n-1}{n}Q_{n-2}(x) & n\geq 2\end{cases}$$

Unfortunately the documentation on these functions is overall not very good, with even Wolfram's usually very reliable reference sites being very poor, see

https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LegendreQ2AbbreviatedGeneral/

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreFunctionoftheSecondKind.html

Hopefully this answer went some way to answer your question.

Comment: I should add - my initial definitions are from [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/14.3)